# Deploy Identity Server4 as a AWS Serverless Lambda Function

Tags: identityserver4

Can we Deploy Identity Server4 as  a AWS Serverless Lambda Function? We have build .net core web application and planning to deploy it as a AWS Lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the development environment version working with the in memory datastore fairly easily with the `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer` NuGet package that lets you run ASP.NET Core applications in Lambda. One gotcha I ran into was by default the ASP.NET Core blueprint that Visual Studio uses creates a API Gateway stage called "Prod" and the uppercase "P" caused problems. So I created a new stage in in all lower case and then it worked of me.

I didn't tackle the issue of using something besides an in memory datastore which would be crucial. I would like to look into using DynamoDB as the datastore so I wouldn't have to have a SQL Server instance.

Comment: We are planning to use EntityFramework Core to store configuration data with identity server4.

Comment: A write-up on how you did it, Norm, would be awesome!

Comment: can you please provide some sample or doc which can help us how to do this?